# How to get all strings that do not contain a word at the end?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

**I have 3 strings:**

```
'Table 1.1 - JDH'
'Table 2.3.4 - continued'
'Table 1.1 - Blahblahblah'
```

**I need to catch only 2 string by *findall()*:**

```
[('Table 1.1', ' - JDH)]
[('Table 1.1', ' - Blahblahblah)]
```

**My regex str in Python 3 is:**

```
'(Table [\.\d]+)^(.+continued)'
```

But it does not work, tell me how it is right?

Comment: Try `'^(?!.*continued)Table \d.*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pattern `^(.+continued)` doesn't match what you want, the `^` is the begin of line anchor and will fail at that point. You need
`((?!.*continued$).+)` instead. which matches `.+` with the assertion doesn't end with `continue`.

Comment: Thx. I use `(Table [\.\d]+)(?!.*continued)` and its work fine.

Comment: ok so you didn't need second capture group, note that removing the end of line anchor `$` this will not match also when `continued`  is not the last word.

Comment: I apologize, of course, it is correct: `'(Table [\.\d]+)((?!.*continued).+)'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
^(?!.*continued$).+
```

---

That is

```
^                 # start of line
(?!.*continued$)  # neg. lookahead
.+                # match 1+ characters
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/GGdLLi/1).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

strings = ['Table 1.1 - JDH', 'Table 2.3.4 - continued', 'Table 1.1 - Blahblahblah']

rx = re.compile(r'^(?!.*continued$).+')

filtered = [string for string in strings if rx.search(string)]
print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `endswith`

```
a = ['Table 1.1 - JDH', 'Table 2.3.4 - continued', 'Table 1.1 - Blahblahblah']
for i in a:
    if not i.endswith("continued"):
        print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
Table 1.1 - JDH
Table 1.1 - Blahblahblah
```